# Функция выполняется дважды

Tags: c

Только начала работать с функциями, столкнулась с проблемой, что функция Enter() выполняется дважды, хотя вызываю я её вроде бы 1 раз. Объясните, в чем дело((

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10
typedef struct
{
    double x1, y1;
    double x2, y2;
}coord;
coord rectang[MAX];
int Enter(coord*, int);
void Print(coord*, int);

void main(void) {
    system("chcp 1251");
    int size; //фактична кількість елементів масиву
    Enter(rectang, MAX);
    Print(rectang, Enter(rectang, MAX));
    getchar();
}

int Enter(coord* mas, int m) {
    int n; //n - номер прямокутника
    char end[MAX];
    printf(" 0 - завершити введення\n");
    for (n = 0; n < m; n++) {
        printf(" Прямокутник №%d\n", n+1);
        printf(" Введіть координати верхньої лівої вершини:\n x1: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &mas[n].x1);
        printf(" y1: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &mas[n].y1);
        printf(" Введіть координати нижньої правої вершини:\n x2: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &mas[n].x2);
        printf(" y2: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &mas[n].y2);
        rewind(stdin);
        gets_s(end);
        if (*end == '0')
            break;
    }
    return n;
 }

 void Print(coord* ar, int k) {
    int m = 0;
    printf("\n\t Таблиця введених даних:");
    printf("\n\t-------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\t|    №    |   ");
    printf("   x1     |   ");
    printf("   y1     |   ");
    printf("   x2     |   ");
    printf("   y2     |   ");
    for (m; m <= k; m++) { // виводимо таблицю
        printf("\n\t-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n\t|    %d.   |   ", m + 1);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", ar[m].x1);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", ar[m].y1);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|   ", ar[m].x2);
        printf(" %-9.2lf|", ar[m].y2);
    }
    printf("\n\t-------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете ее два раза.

```
//Enter(rectang, MAX); - первый вызов
Print(rectang, Enter(rectang, MAX)); // - второй вызов
```

или

```
size = Enter(rectang, MAX); // - один вызов
Print(rectang, size);
```